# Why does log analytics show no logs for my Synapse Pipelines?

Tags: logging, azure-synapse, workspace, azure-log-analytics

I have a Synapse pipeline with a single Wait task (just to record that a pipeline has started and finished). There are no log entries records in log analytics even after I run the pipeline several times but can't see what I've missed. Can anyone shed some light on what I may have missed please? I'm only interested in the logs of pipeline runs, not anything like Spark or SQL logging.

I've created a Log Analytics workspace that has reader and contributor access granted to it for my Synapse workspace's managed identity . I've also configured the Synapse workspace under Diagnostic Settings to record Integration Pipeline Runs, Activity Runs, and Trigger runs. I have set this to record logs in the log analytics workspace which appears in the subscription and workspace drop-downs (both values populated with what I'd expect).